# I need php function to get the current user location like street name

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the user location using php and mysql

The question is

Arethere any php functions or libraries that can get the current user location like **street name and city name**

Comment: It's not possible to collect user current location & street name without help google Map API.

Comment: can you give me any help about google Map API

Comment: see this below link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/geolocation   You can store user current location in your database & show all user current location in front-end view with php.

Comment: location based on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this link here: [PHP Detect Country and City](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8163-PHP-Get-the-current-user-location-using-codehelper-io.html#view_files)

This class can get the current user location using codehelper.io API.

It can determine the current user IP address checking the user remote IP address eventually behind a proxy server.

The class can send a HTTP request to the codehelper.io API to get the geographic location details associated to the user IP address.

It returns the continent, country, city, latitude, longitude and other details associated to the location city.

The class caches the locations for the given IP address for one week.